# Distortion-free Panorama Render (NOT equirectangular)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to get a render of a full 360° panorama without distortion on the receding horizontal edges. See attached image.

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

This [image: blender cycles render detail with markup]is the result with an equirectangular Panorama camera in Cycles, with the longitude set to a 30° range. I'm trying to get perspective-style presentation, no warping or distortion at all if possible.

I'm using Blender 3.1 on Mac.